# How to intercept UIScrollView scrolling event?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin! `Scrolled` is fired, but it doesn't contain X and Y info. I need to know when the view is scrolled to adjust some Views for them to look like they aren't moving. `DraggingEnded` is fired only when the scroll is over and that's too late. How to receive changes as soon as they are made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class ScrollViewDelegate : UIScrollViewDelegate
{
    public ScrollViewDelegate()
    {
        //...
    }
    public override void DraggingStarted(UIScrollView scrollView)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Dragging started offset: " + scrollView.ContentOffset);
    }
}

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SomeScrollViewControl), typeof(SomeScrollView))]
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class SomeScrollView : ViewRenderer<SomeScrollViewControl, SomeScrollView>
    {
        public SomeScrollView()
        {
            //...
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<SomeScrollViewControl> e)
        {
            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                //Create someScrollView...
                someScrollView.Delegate = new ScrollViewDelegate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `UIScrollView` subclass, override the `ContentOffset` property and monitor the `set` and you will get new X/Y of the view as the user scrolls/pans arounds.

```
public override CoreGraphics.CGPoint ContentOffset
{
    get
    {
        return base.ContentOffset;
    }
    set
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{value.X}:{value.Y}");
        base.ContentOffset = value;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
39.0704398717043:41.4920965388485
35.3280093038005:36.4695722954986
31.736242067681:31.6492455873442
28.1199544514634:26.7960113338755
24.5949600095583:22.0652969703334
21.2827079155381:17.6200932075763
17.9479795925504:13.1447252499626
```